# How to convert an HTML <div..../div> into a javascript object with name:value properties?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a text file containing multiple HTML div's e.g.

```
<div id="ID_a" name="VEC" class="cat" title ="scene,-12, 0.5, 0, 1" text = "$\omega =9$">   </div>  
<div id="ID_b" name="VEC" class="cat" title ="scene,-12, 0.5, 0, 3" text = "$\alfa = 2$">   </div>  
<div id="ID_c" name="VEC" class="cat" title ="scene,-12, 0.5, 0, 4" text = "$\beta = 30.5$"></div>  
<div id="ID_d" name="VEC" class="cat" title ="scene,-12, 0.5, 0, 2" text = "$\gamma = 90$"> </div>
```

I wish to convert (using javascript) each `<div ...> </div>` statement in the text into a javascript object specification statement e.g.

```
Coll[1] = {id:"ID_a", name: "VEC", class: "cat", title:"scene,-12, 0.5, 0, 1", text = "$\omega =9$" }; 
Coll[2] = {id:"ID_a", name: "VEC", class: "cat", title:"scene,-12, 0.5, 0, 3", text = "$\alfa = 2$" }; 
Coll[3] = {id:"ID_a", name: "VEC", class: "cat", title:"scene,-12, 0.5, 0, 4", text = "$\beta = 30.5$" }; 
Coll[4] = {id:"ID_a", name: "VEC", class: "cat", title:"scene,-12, 0.5, 0, 2", text = "$\gamma = 90$" };
```

I wonder if there a simple way to do this?

EDIT: I want to do it in plain javascript without using the DOM model or loading the divs as part of an html file.  Sorry for not making this clear before.

Comment: Read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll Then update your question with any specific issues you have with your code.

Comment: Divs area already accessible from JavaScript using the DOM (document object model) - I would just work with the DOM object rather than go through intermediate representations. If you need to serialize a DOM tree I'd use the standard format (HTML)

Comment: @daddygames, sorry I didnt make it clear that I want to do it in plain javscript without using DOM/HTML.

Comment: @ Benjamin Gruenbaum, sorry I didnt make it clear that I want to do it in plain javscript without using DOM/HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you load all the divs as strings you can [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) each string to an object. This can be done by [splitting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) the string (via [regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)) by each attribute and then converting those strings into in object via [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

Because some values contain an equal sign i search for the index of the first occurence and split the string into a key and value with [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) before returning it as an object.

```js
const divs = [
  '<div id="ID_a" name="VEC" class="cat" title ="scene,-12, 0.5, 0, 1" text = "$\omega =9$">   </div>',
  '<div id="ID_b" name="VEC" class="cat" title ="scene,-12, 0.5, 0, 3" text = "$\alfa = 2$">   </div>',
  '<div id="ID_c" name="VEC" class="cat" title ="scene,-12, 0.5, 0, 4" text = "$\beta = 30.5$"></div>',
  '<div id="ID_d" name="VEC" class="cat" title ="scene,-12, 0.5, 0, 2" text = "$\gamma = 90$"> </div>',
];

const Coll = divs.map((div) => {
  const parts = div.match(/[\w-]+\s?=\s?"[^"]*"/g);

  const objectified = parts.reduce((obj, str) => {
    const index = str.indexOf("=");
    const key = str.slice(0, index);
    const value = str.slice(index + 1, str.length);

    obj[key] = value;

    return obj;
  }, {});
  
  return objectified;
});

console.log("Single value:", Coll[0].id);
console.log(Coll);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: (1) Theres some interesting & powerful techniques that are new to me and I need to study. (2) At the start the divs are not separate strings so I'd need to convert the text blob into strings first. (3) When I ran the code snippet the result was not 100% as desired because too many double quotes and backslashes.  But very useful all the same, thanks :)

Comment: If the strings are not seperated you can just split them by the newline symbol (`\n`) unless they are all on the same line. As of the extra quotes and slashes. This is because your code already contains double quotes. The extra characters are only visible in the console. The values are still the same, i changed my snippet to also log a single value, as you can see there it has no extra quotes or slashes. Read the section [Escape notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) this explains it better.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are looking for?

```js
let divs = document.querySelectorAll('div');

let obj = [];

divs.forEach(element => {
  let e = {
    id: element.id,
    name: element.getAttribute("name"),
    class: element.className,
    title: element.title,
    text: element.getAttribute("text")
  };
  obj.push(e);
})

console.log(obj)
```

```html
<div id="ID_a" name="VEC" class="cat" title="scene,-12, 0.5, 0, 1" text="$\omega =9$"> </div>
<div id="ID_b" name="VEC" class="cat" title="scene,-12, 0.5, 0, 3" text="$\alfa = 2$"> </div>
<div id="ID_c" name="VEC" class="cat" title="scene,-12, 0.5, 0, 4" text="$\beta = 30.5$"></div>
<div id="ID_d" name="VEC" class="cat" title="scene,-12, 0.5, 0, 2" text="$\gamma = 90$"> </div>
```

Comment: (1)That looks close to my target. (2) I ran the code snippet; results  have the property names (e.g. id,name,class, title, text) inside double quotes e.g. "id" , they should not be. (3) The MathML single backslashes have become double backslashes e.g. "\\alfa".

Comment: (4) the first line of your code assumes I am using DOM but actually I want to do this in plain javascript. Sorry I should have made that clearer in my question :)

Comment: (5) I didnt spot it before I tried it but now I see that you are also using DOM for the `element.` which rules out this answer for my current requirement.